# Algorithm for determining the differentiability of a single variable real function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What would be an appropriate algorithm, for students of first year calculus, to determine where a given function is differentiable ?

When a function is defined by cases, as in
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x\le 1\\ x^2, & x>1 \end{cases}$$
clearly one has to resort to the definition for the points of stitching, like $x=1$ in the above function.

What about points where the function is defined as an elementary function. Would it be correct to find the formula for the derivative, and say that the function is not differentiable where the derivative is not defined ? For instance, let
$$ f(x) = \arcsin \sqrt{1-x^2}.$$
The derivative is
$$ f'(x) = \frac{-x}{|x| \sqrt{1-x^2}},$$
which is not defined for $x=\pm1,0$. Indeed, $f$ is not differentiable at these points. Is this always the case ?

Comment: Differentiability implies continuity. So if a function is discontinuous at any point then it cannot be differentiable. What you can do is search for points of discontinuity in both the original function and in the derivative. If you wanted to go for theory and look at a specific point only, then you could plug that point into the limit definition of the derivative. Clearly if the limit doesn't exist then the function is not differentiable at that point.